# No login prompt after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I just updated my ubuntu server 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS via apt-get do-release-upgrade.

There haven't been any error messages but after the reboot, no login prompt appears. Just a black screen, sometimes with a blinking cursor on the top left.

Nevertheless login via ssh and LAN still works perfectly.

Any ideas what could have happened and how I could solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (well, exact same symptoms anyway) with the upgrade, in my case dpkg apparently had a hickup sometime during the process.

This was easily fixed by running

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

on the command line (you can get to a console via Ctrl+Alt+F1 and login).

Resolved the issue, and installation appeared to be in perfect shape afterwards.

Comment: Great Thank you! With Ctrl+Alt+F1 I get the login prompt. Dpkg on the other hand doesn't change anything. But when googling for Ctrl Alt F1 I get the feeling that I don't really have a problem. Is it possible that it's standard behaviour of ubuntu 16 not to show a login prompt on the local console? (I'm running the server version)